# How to get internet from wifi and share to LAN device

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, internet-sharing

In my apartment, I can only connect to the internet via apartment's Wifi hotspot. But I have a multiple devices that have only LAN connection such as PC, Internet TV, game console. All I have are DLINK wireless router(DSL-264OBT) and USB wireless adapter.

Objective: I'd like to access an internet from those devices.

Is it possible to use wireless router to connect to wifi hotspot and then share an internet to LAN via its own Ethernet port ?

One solution I can think of is to connect USB wireless adapter to PC and then share internet via router's LAN. But this way, If I want to play games, I have to turn on my PC all the time even I don't use it at all.

Anyone has solution for this ? It's OK for me to buy a new network device if it needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a wireless bridge, most home routers won't have that option without a custom firmware, but i believe a few d-links I've had have actually had that option and is actually how i have my HTPC, tv and PS3 connected to my home network at home, using a cheap linksys router that has ddwrt on it it

If you need something temporary you can use a laptop to create a bridge from your wireless to your wired NIC without using any extra software, [here's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126153%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) a guide that has some info on it from technet.

DD-WRT is a custom firmware that would be able to get the job done with any compatible wireless router.

You can find the Router database for it [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database), your current dlink isn't supported how ever.

Comment: Which one do you think is the better choice between router that has DD-WRT support or the access point that is able to do wireless bridge?

Comment: I personally prefer DD-WRT, you can even get a couple of them running and set them up to do repeat-bridging. If it comes down to it, they have routers with dd-wrt pre-installed that all run really solidly.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your router has a wireless bridging mode (my cheap TP-Link calls this WDS bridging) in the set up. You set the network name and password to be the same as your apartment's wifi.

You would then need to to turn off the DHCP server on your router (so that your kit connected to your router get their IP address etc from yout apartment's wifi router).

You could, however, have performance problems if other clients use your router wirelessly in preference to the apartment's router as your router would be receiving and then retransmitting any network traffic.

Comment: I have checked my router and there's no feature like that. I've done some research and found out that many access point has that feature. Which one is a better choice between new wireless router that has wireless bridge or access point? (or wireless router that has DD-WRT support - sorry just seen charles.schlue comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use connectify software from http://www.connectify.me/ then if your NIC or wireless adapter is compatible with this software you can share your internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connectify as Anees already suggested.

Also, running a proxy server on your laptop is a perfect use case for proxy.

Basically your laptop will connect to the wifi hotspot, and also to your router through a lan cable.

Other devices are also connected to your router through lan cable.

The purpose of router here is simply to act as a dhcp server and assign ips to all your devices.

Now run a proxy server on your laptop on a port.

This proxy can be used by the devices to access the hotspot's internet.

Answer (score -1):

As Simple as ABC...
Right Click your wireless adopter
Select Properties...
go to sharing tab
Click share
select your local area network in drop down list.

This will share your wifi internet to local computer connected through LAN...